# How to get github to show my jupyter notebook images?

Tags: github, formatting, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Github is not showing the images in my jupyter notebook.

I have tried pushing different formats such as:

```
![alt text](img/file.png)
```

and

```
<img src="img/file.png", width=200, height=200>
```

which they do work on my local jupyter notebooks in regards of showing images, but once I pushed these notebooks to Github, everything works fine in my repository, but the images won't show.

[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhZVF.png)

Comment: are you uploading your images to github as well, and keeping the relative paths the same?

Comment: I was uploading the images to my Github repository into a folder named 'images', but like you mentioned, I tried to move them outside of the folder into the same path as my file report and that fixed the problem. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you repost it as an answer, I would give you points as accepted answer for the reference you gave me on switching the path of my files.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, when something like this happens please ensure that you are uploading the relevant files and that the path you are uploading the files to is still valid relative to the notebook.